# Data is not retrieving from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

**This is my index.php file**

**I am not getting any data from Mysql database. Page is loading empty, it is not loading or fetching any results from database. Please help me. Thanks**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sty.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css" />       
</head>
<body>
 <div id='data'></div>
</body>


<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"; integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuEL‌​A=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


     $.ajax({

             type: "GET",
             url: "get_data.php",
             data: {
                 'offset':1,
                 'limit' :5
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#data').html(data);
            }

       });

    });


</script>

</html>
```

**And this is my get_data.php file**

```
<?php



    if(isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])){

        $limit = $_GET['limit'];
        $offset = $_GET['offset'];  

        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'text');

        $data = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `text` LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
          echo '<div id="post1"><p>'.$row['text'].'</p></div>';
         }
    }




?>
```

**This is My database structure**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 12, 2017 at 09:08 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.19-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.0.13

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `text`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `text`
--

CREATE TABLE `text` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `text` longtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `text`
--

INSERT INTO `text` (`id`, `image`, `text`) VALUES
(1, '', ''),
(2, '', 'hi'),
(3, '', 'hhh'),
(4, '', 'dgg'),
(5, '', 'hfg'),
(6, '', 'hfg'),
(7, '', 'hhhhh'),
(8, '', 'hi'),
(9, '', '1'),
(10, '', '2'),
(11, '', '3'),
(12, '', '4'),
(13, '', '5'),
(14, '', '4'),
(15, '', '1'),
(16, '', '1'),
(17, '', '3'),
(18, '', '121'),
(19, '', '45457'),
(20, '', 'hh'),
(21, '', '45'),
(22, '', 'fgsgf'),
(23, '', '45454545'),
(24, '', 'jj'),
(25, '', 'fafads'),
(26, '', 'asf'),
(27, '', 'fsdfsfg'),
(28, '', '1'),
(29, '', ''),
(30, '', ''),
(31, '', ''),
(32, '', ''),
(33, '', ''),
(34, '', ''),
(35, '', ''),
(36, '', ''),
(37, '', ''),
(38, '', '');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `text`
--
ALTER TABLE `text`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `text`
--
ALTER TABLE `text`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=39;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

[index image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTcBD.jpg)

[get data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcrIH.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried hitting the url from the browser. Open the URL in browser `http://localhost/... /get_data.php?offset=10&limit=0` and check the output is the as you wanted. This is to check wether your php code have some error or not

Comment: Please add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of both your files

Comment: try viewing your apache error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mysqli error function here is:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])){
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'text');
if(isset($_GET["limit"])){
 $limit = $_GET['limit'];
}
else{
 $limit=5;
}

if(isset($_GET["offset"])){
 $offset = $_GET['offset'];
}
else{
 $offset=1;
}

$data = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `text` LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset")or die(mysqli_error($connection));


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
     echo '<div id="post1"><p>'.$row['text'].'</p></div>';
    }
}

?>
```

This gives you a error if there is error in you sql query.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139394/discussion-on-answer-by-bharat-savani-data-is-not-retrieving-from-mysql-database).

Answer (score 0):

Your'e getting blank output cause no GET parameter is sent to get_data.php. Try this:

```
url: "get_data.php?offset=foo&limit=bar",
```

Comment: ajax get request pass parameter in url

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are coding always try to catch all the exception that you can.

In your ajax call you are not handling the fail case so you can't find it where you are going wrong.

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_data.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'offset': 1,
            'limit': 5
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').append(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            alert(msg);
        }

    });
```